# Unable to install package nextcloud-client on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I want to install nextcloud-client on my Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan). To achieve this I followed the [instructions](https://launchpad.net/~nextcloud-devs/+archive/ubuntu/client):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nextcloud-devs/client
sudo apt-get update
```

The `update` statement shows that the ppa was added:

```
...
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nextcloud-devs/client/ubuntu eoan InRelease
...
```

Installing the package fails:

```
sudo apt install nextcloud-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nextcloud-client
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Try to search the package with "apt-cache search nextcloud"

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Good idea. This command returns multiple hits, but I can not identify which belongs to my freshly added ppa. Because of this I ran `apt-cache search -f nextcloud | grep "Version: 2"` There is no `2.6` in the list, this is the version I expect to be in the ppa. I only see `2.5.3-1` and older.

Comment: The deb package isn't available on the [archive directory](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nextcloud-devs/client/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nextcloud-client/) , only the source is available. Also building nextcloud-client from source on  Ubuntu Eoan will fail with Unmet and missing dependencies. (e,g: `kdelibs5-dev` isn't available for Eoan)

Comment: why don't you write an answer , what you are saying is definitely right !

Comment: @GAD3R ah, I didn't expect this. Are there alternatives for 19.10 ?

Comment: I have updated my answer , nextcloud-client can be installed on ubuntu 19.10  from the beta repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.deb` package isn't available on the [archive directory](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nextcloud-devs/client/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nextcloud-client/) , only the source is available. Also building `nextcloud-client` from source on Ubuntu Eoan will fail with Unmet and missing [dependencies](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nextcloud-devs/client/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nextcloud-client/nextcloud-client_2.6.0-20190927.150124~bionic1.dsc). e,g: [`kdelibs5-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdelibs5-dev) isn't available for Eoan

**Update**

The `nextcloud-client` can be installed on Ubuntu 19.10 from the [beta repository](https://launchpad.net/~nextcloud-devs/+archive/ubuntu/client-beta):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nextcloud-devs/client-beta
sudo apt install nextcloud-client
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. From the beta repo I get a 2.7 version, at present there is no official version of nextcloud with that number. Is this some 2.6 based version with a "fake" version to differentiate beta and non-beta repo ?

Comment: @Marged It is a testing repository which contain the latest build , it can be used until a new upload is done in the stable repository. As you can see the repository is very active , every day  , a new [upload is available](https://launchpad.net/~nextcloud-devs/+archive/ubuntu/client-beta/+packages).

Comment: My point was more that I don't know of a 2.7 version of nextcloud-client. The releases on github show 2.6.1-rc for example, but no 2.7. And the testing repository does not contain any 2.6 version at all. This is what I was trying to understandt